# Can 'Elevated privileges' be used in SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, runwithelevatedprivileges

I want to migrate my farm solution from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019. I have **RunWithElevatedPrivileges** method used in SP2010 solution. Can it be used in SP2019 also?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like yes.

According to the [MS documentation page for `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges?view=sharepoint-server), it applies to the "Latest" version of SharePoint Server.

[image: screenshot of MS documentation page]